# Add Home page link to AppBar using Material-UI

Tags: react-router, material-ui

I'm new to React and am trying to add a "Home" page link to the AppBar component of Material-UI (version 4.0.1). The behaviour I'd like to see is that when clicking the "Home" link that component "OnePage" is displayed.

In "OnePage" there is a link to another component "TwoPage", which should be the only content displayed when clicking on "ViewTwo page". However, currently both OnePage and TwoPage are displayed.

Any help sorting out the navigation issue would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the relevant files.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import OnePage from './OnePage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <SearchBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={OnePage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**SearchBar/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));

function SearchBar() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <NavLink to="/">
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                            Home
                        </Typography>
                    </NavLink>
                    <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(SearchBar);
```

**OnePage/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';

import TwoPage from '../TwoPage';



class OnePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <span>Test Page 1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Link to='/twoPage'>View Two page</Link>
                    </div>

                    <Route path="/twoPage" exact render={() => <TwoPage />} />
                </Router>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(OnePage);
```

**TwoPage/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';



class TwoPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Test Page 2</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default TwoPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are defining second page inside new `Router` component. You should have one root `Router` component to work properly. You don't need to wrap with `withRouter` HOC if you're using `<Link/>` to point to route defined in `<Route/>`

Working example:-

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>

        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Route exact path="/" component={OnePage} />
        <Route path="/twoPage" component={TwoPage} />  
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function OnePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <li>
        <Link to="/twoPage">Two Page</Link>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}

function TwoPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>TwoPage</h2>
    </div>
  );
}


export default BasicExample;
```